# PyCharm indexing occupied too much memory?

Tags: memory, pycharm

Every time I open PyCharm on my mbp (8GB memory), it takes a long time to index and occupies almost 90% of memory.

Is there any way to prevent PyCharm from occupying too much memory when it starts?

Comment: Yes, get a gtx 1080, top of the line cpu and smile proudly.  That and send them a support ticket and expect a lot of tweaking.  This is a pc optimisation issue...

Comment: Nice advice. I guess I need to upgrade my device.

Comment: Why would you want to prevent PyCharm from utilizing as much resources for indexing as you have? Do you want to process to be slower?